# Duplicate class found in modules

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am working on a multi module Android project. One of the modules which was written previously used Paging library version-2, now I am trying to use the new paging v3 library in another module, but I am getting this error.

`Duplicate class androidx.paging.LivePagedListKt found in modules jetified-paging-runtime-ktx-2.1.2-runtime.jar (androidx.paging:paging-runtime-ktx:2.1.2) and paging-runtime-3.0.0-alpha03-runtime.jar (androidx.paging:paging-runtime:3.0.0-alpha03)`

The module hierarchy is this way:

```
       app:
   /         \
module-A    module-B
(uses v2)   (uses v3)
```

I have added dependencies of module A and module B in the app module build.gradle like this

```
implementation project(path: ':module-A')
implementation project(path: ':module-B')
```

**Is there any way we can use different versions of the same library in the same project, provided that the different versions are used in separate modules**.

Solutions tried so far:

I looked through similar answers and added this line in app level build.gradle file

```
configurations {
    runtime.exclude group: 'androidx.paging', module: 'paging-runtime'
}
```

but still getting the same error.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did anyone know some solution?

Comment: I couldn't find any solution, I just ended up using the same version of the library in all modules.

Answer (score 2):

The snippet:

```
configurations {
    runtime.exclude group: 'androidx.paging', module: 'paging-runtime'
}
```

would only work if the v2 library was included in the `runtime` configuration. You should adjust the configuration for whatever configuration you have the v2 library declared in (`implementation`, `api`, the deprecated `compile`, whatever).

You're probably using `implementation`, so try this snippet:

```
configurations {
    implementation.exclude group: 'androidx.paging', module: 'paging-runtime-ktx'
}
```

with or without `-ktx`.

Or use this snippet which should work regardless of the configuration you are using:

```
configurations.all {
    exclude group: 'androidx.paging', module: 'paging-runtime-ktx'
}
```

Source: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_downgrade_and_exclude.html#sec:excluding-transitive-deps